spresenseのマルチコア機能を使って複数のアナログセンサを使いたい
sub1とsub2とにそれぞれアナログ入力の距離センサ（シャープ測距センサ）をA1とA3に入力しております。
それぞれの値をシリアルモニタで表示しているのですが、A3の値しか表示されません。
sub1にA1とA3の両方を書くと、正常にA1とA3の値がそれぞれ表示されます。
アナログ入力でsub1とsub2に分けて入力を読むことがそもそもできないのでしょうか？
sub1とsub2は同じスケッチで、ピン番号などが違うだけです。
（以下、sub1のスケッチ）
#if (SUBCORE != 1)  //または2
#error "Core selection is wrong!!"
#endif

#include <MP.h>

float Vcc = 5.0;//電源電圧
float distance_1;   //sub2は3
float distance_2;   //sub2は4
const int ANALOG1 = A1;//sub2はA3

void setup(){
  
   Serial.begin(9600);//シリアル通信
   MP.begin();
  }

void loop(){ 
  
     MPLog();

 distance_1 = Vcc*analogRead(ANALOG1)/1023; 
 distance_2 = 26.549*pow(distance_1,-1.2091); //距離換算
 
 Serial.print(distance_2); //sub2は4
 Serial.print ("cm,   "); 
 delay(100); 
}


リソース競合が発生してアナログ端子をコアごとに分けて読み出すことはできないようです。
Mainコアで各アナログ端子を周期的に読み出してメモリに保存しておいて、
各サブコアではその結果を読み出すだけにすることでシンプルに実装できそうです。
Mainコア (周期タスクによりA1, A3を読み出してメモリに保存)
#ifdef SUBCORE
#error "Core selection is wrong!!"
#endif

#include <MP.h>

#define STACKSIZE 1024
#define PRIORITY  110

static int AIN1;
static int AIN3;

static int ain(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  while (1) {
    AIN1 = analogRead(A1);
    AIN3 = analogRead(A3);
    usleep(10 * 1000);
  }
  return 0;
}

void setup()
{
  int subcore;
  Serial.begin(115200);

  task_create("ain", PRIORITY, STACKSIZE, ain, NULL);

  /* Boot SubCore */
  subcore = 1;
  MP.begin(subcore);
  MP.Send(100, &AIN1, subcore);
  MPLog("@AIN1=0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)&AIN1);

  subcore = 2;
  MP.begin(subcore);
  MP.Send(100, &AIN3, subcore);
  MPLog("@AIN3=0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)&AIN3);
}

void loop()
{
  sleep(1);
}

Sub1コア (A1読み出し)
#ifndef SUBCORE
#error "Core selection is wrong!!"
#endif

#include <MP.h>

static int *AIN1;

void setup()
{
  int8_t msgid;

  MP.begin();
  MP.Recv(&msgid, (uint32_t*)&AIN1);
  MPLog("@AIN1=0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)AIN1);
}

void loop()
{
  MPLog("A1=%d\n", *AIN1);
  delay(100);
}

Sub2コア (A3読み出し)
#ifndef SUBCORE
#error "Core selection is wrong!!"
#endif

#include <MP.h>

static int *AIN3;

void setup()
{
  int8_t msgid;

  MP.begin();
  MP.Recv(&msgid, (uint32_t*)&AIN3);
  MPLog("@AIN3=0x%08x\n", (uint32_t)AIN3);
}

void loop()
{
  MPLog("A3=%d\n", *AIN3);
  delay(100);
}


具体的にご教示いただきありがとうございます。
ご教示いただいた内容で再トライしてみます。
ありがとうございます。

CPUはいくつも入ってるだろうけど、ADコンバータは一つしか内蔵されてません
アナログ入力ピンがたくさんあるといっても、単にADコンバータの入力を切り替えてやってるだけなんで、「同時に」複数のピンでのアナログ変換はできません
ってことで、シングルスレッドで順番に取り込んでいってそれを利用するってことでやっていきましょう
